# How to troubleshoot my JSX/CSS so that this mess doesn't happen?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I have a toggle that changes temperatures from celsius to fahrenheit in a weather app. The code goes like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Temperature extends Component {
  state = {
    unit: "metrics"
  };

  imperial = () => {
    this.setState({
      unit: "imperial",
      imperialTemp: Math.round(this.props.temp * (9 / 5) + 32),
      imperialMin: Math.round(this.props.temp1 * (9 / 5) + 32),
      imperialMax: Math.round(this.props.temp2 * (9 / 5) + 32)
    });
  };

  metrics = () => {
    this.setState({
      unit: "metrics"
    });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.unit === "metrics") {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="temp">
            {this.props.temp}ºC |
            <span className="fahrenheit" onClick={this.imperial}>
              °F
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
              <div className="min-max">
                {this.props.temp1}ºC |
                <span className="fahrenheit" onClick={this.imperial}>
                  °F
                </span>{" "}
                | {this.props.temp2}ºC |
                <span className="fahrenheit" onClick={this.imperial}>
                  °F
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="temp">
            {this.state.imperialTemp}
            <span className="celsius" onClick={this.metrics}>
              ºC |
            </span>
            ºF
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
              <div className="min-max">
                {this.state.imperialMin}
                <span className="celsius" onClick={this.metrics}>
                  ºC |
                </span>
                ºF | {this.state.imperialMax}
                <span className="celsius" onClick={this.metrics}>
                  ºC |
                </span>
                ºF
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Temperature;
```

The problem is that instead of a clean image I get this mess[image: Mess]

It gets even worse when I click the ºF to change into fahrenheit; [image: Mess2]

Since I'm only adding one current temperature line and one min/max line per condition, why is this happening? Why is it showing two of each? And what's up with the ºCs? Any suggestions of what's going on? Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

I was rendering the Temperature component twice, that is why the first image is happening. Now it happily shows this [image: Nice]

However the mess with the Cs persists:

[image: Mess3]

Help!

Comment: Are you sure that the `celsius` CSS has no problems? it should be similar to `fahrenheit` class. Maybe some problem with the CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you posted, it looks like the `temp1` and `temp2` props are not numbers, and that you're rendering the `Temperature` component twice.

It's difficult to know without seeing the parent component however. It would help to update your code with the parent, where you're rendering `Temperature`.

The issue `°C`s looks like an issue with the `celsius` class, it would also help if you posted that code.

Note: You could simplify this code if you toggle the data in state, rather than conditionally rendering 2 almost identical UIs. Something like this:

```
class Temperature extends Component {
  state = {
    unit: "metrics",
    tempClass: "celsius",
    temp: this.props.initialTemp,
    tempMin: this.props.initialTemp1,
    tempMax: this.props.initialTemp2
  };

  toggleUnits = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => prevState.unit === "metrics" ? {
      unit: "imperial",
      tempClass: "fahrenheit",
      temp: this.toFahrenheit(prevState.temp),
      tempMin: this.toFahrenheit(prevState.tempMin),
      tempMax: this.toFahrenheit(prevState.tempMax)
    } : {
      unit: "metrics",
      tempClass: "celsius",
      temp: this.toCelsius(prevState.temp),
      tempMin: this.toCelsius(prevState.tempMin),
      tempMax: this.toCelsius(prevState.tempMax)
    });
  };

  toFahrenheit = temp => Math.round(temp * (9 / 5) + 32)
  toCelsius = temp => Math.round((temp - 32) * (5 / 9))

  render() {
      const { temp, tempClass, tempMin, tempMax } = this.state;

      return (
        <div>
          <div className="temp">
            {temp}ºC |
            <span className={tempClass} onClick={this.toggleUnits}>
              °F
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
              <div className="min-max">
                {tempMin}ºC |
                <span className={tempClass} onClick={this.toggleUnits}>
                  °F
                </span>{" "}
                | {tempMax}ºC |
                <span className={tempClass} onClick={this.toggleUnits}>
                  °F
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: You were right, I was stupidly rendering Temperature twice. I fixed that issue. However the problem with the Cs persists.

Comment: I've updated my answer, take a look at the `celsius` class and see if anything looks off.